# php functions using with smarty template

Tags: php, function, smarty

please give some note about php functions using with smarty template

Comment: If someone votes down the question/ can they say why.  Mate sort your question out, it dont make any sense.

Comment: Are you asking if you can call PHP functions from within Smarty templates?

Comment: Maybe he's not that familiar with the english language - so not blaming here. I guess he wants to know, if he can use php-functions within smarty templates. The answer would be yes.

Comment: yeah ... exactly .. wanna to know about that.. if u can .. plz help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty does allow you to call PHP functions, but it's assumed that you shouldn't need to and so it's not as easy as it could be. The general philosophy of Smarty is that you should avoid tying your templates too closely to your application code (i.e. the PHP), as this would make Smarty itself somewhat redundant.

This thread may be of use:

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=46985

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the  smarty template engine does work with PHP. If you wish to have a look at a tutorial [have a look at the smarty website.](http://www.smarty.net/crash_course)