# How to parse & get url of the <img> tag from HTML using smarty and php?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have a smarty variable which holds the HTML content as value. Inside the HTML content there is an image. I have to extract the url of that image for resize purposes.

I know there is a way to parse it in php and assign to smarty variable. But I need to know whether there is any method in smarty like regex to get the url of the `<img>`tag from HTML.

example:

```
{$post_content|regex_replace:"/(<img>|<img [^>]*>|<\\/>)/":""}
```

This is the code to escape `<img>` tag alone.  Likewise I need to get the url of the image from the `$post_content` variable.

Comment: atleast show your smarty variable

Answer (score 0):

smarty is just a template engine. not a different language.

so whatever you can do in php can also be done in smarty.

so use php dom parsers :)

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385382/php-functions-using-with-smarty-template)

and [check this](http://www.smarty.net/crash_course)

one says u cant use php function and other says, but what i say is yes you can use php functions before assigning it to the template engine.

Comment: Dude! I'm aware that we can use php functions before assigning to smarty variable. But I need to find is there any easy way in smarty to minimize the codes!